# How to trigger the input focus event inside a method in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have an input for which is using the following event :

```
 <b-nput
            class="input"
            id="link"
            v-model="link"
            placeholder="link"
            @focus="$event.target.select()"
          ></b-input>
```

How can I use this `@focus="$event.target.select()"`  event inside:

The above method copies the value. I need to trigger the above select focus event when the user clicks copy
How can be it achieved correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `saved` method as focus event handler :

```
@focus="saved"
```

method :

```
methods: {
  saved(event){ //the event is passed automatically as parameter
     event.target.select()
  }
}
```

Edit :

Try to add `ref` to the input element

```
 <b-input
          ref="input"
            class="input"
            id="link"
            v-model="link"
            placeholder="link"
         
            @focus="$event.target.select()"
          ></b-input>
```

then inside the method trigger the focus programmatically :

```
 methods: {
      async copy(s) {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(s) 
      this.$refs.input.focus();
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, saved method is another method where I need to trigger it as well

Comment: please explain more the scenario

Comment: There is a method which copies the value besides the focus above method I need to trigger the above select when the user clicks copy

  async copy(s) {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(s)
}

Comment: Please try to edit the question with these details and explain more the desired behavior

Comment: It seems working but has only one issue. I am using the same copy method for 2 inputs when I use the same ref it selects first only when I add to refs in the same method it selects only for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `$event` reference to the `saved` method

```
  <b-nput
        class="input"
        id="link"
        v-model="link"
        placeholder="link"
        @focus="saved"
      ></b-input>


methods: {
  saved(event){
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

ref - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Give a `ref` to your input :

```
<b-input
            class="input"
            id="link"
            v-model="link"
            placeholder="link"
            ref="theInput"
          ></b-input>
```

then anywhere in your Component script :

```
this.$refs['theInput'].focus();
```